# Joint distributions of the rvs $X_1,X_2$ which are exchangeable and only take values from $\{0,1\}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**The Problem:** Describe all possible joint distributions of the random variables $X_1,X_2$ which are exchangeable and only take values from $\{0,1\}.$

**My Thoughts:** First I observe that by exchangeability we have $P(X_1=0,X_2=1)=P(X_1=1,X_2=0)$. Setting $P(X_1=0,X_2=1)=p$, we have that $P(X_1=X_2)=1-p$. Then $P(X_1=0,X_2=0)+P(X_1=1,X_2=1)=1-p.$ But I don't know how to proceed from here.

**My Concerns:** I think I have not understood the question clearly. Could anyone shed some light into whether my approach is on the right track or I have failed to understand what is being asked of me to do?
Thank you for your time and appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support of the joint distribution has only $4$ points, and the pmf at two of those points is the same, as you already figured out. Coupled with the restriction that all probabilities sum to one, we have $2$ degrees of freedom. Now let $P(X=Y=0)=a$ and $P(X=Y=1)=b$ where $0\le a,b,a+b\le1$. Then $P(X=0,Y=1)=P(X=1,Y=0)=\frac{1-a-b}2$.

This describes all possible admissible joint distributions.